# Filling an array with unknown size in fortran90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I want to fill an array with unknown size in fortran90.
This is the equivalent code in MATLAB  :

```
for i=1:10
 A[i] = i
end
```

I know that i can pass the size, but 
How can i do this in fortran90 without passing the size of the array. I read that we can use pointers, but i really dont know how to deal with pointers

Comment: Do you know about allocatable arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase array size on-the-fly in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384406/how-to-increase-array-size-on-the-fly-in-fortran)

Comment: Nopm i dont know about allocation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand you want to start adding elements to an array before you know the final size of the array.

As an example, you want to read values from a file until you reach the end of the file, not knowing how many values there are.

There are three ways I can think of:

1. Create an array of sufficient size, and remember the final value.

   ```
    integer :: a(200), n
    n = 1
    do
        a(n) = <value>
        if (<finished>) exit
        n = n + 1
    end do

    <use a(1:n)>
   ```
2. Create two allocatable arrays, when you reach the end of one, make the other bigger, and swap them:

   ```
    integer, allocatable :: a(:), tmp(:)
    integer :: i, n
    n = 8
    allocate(a(n))
    i = 1
    do
        if (i > n) then 
            allocate(tmp(2*n))
            tmp(1:n) = a(:)
            call move_alloc(tmp, a)
            n = n * 2
        end if
        a(i) = <value>
        if (<finished>) exit
        i = i + 1
    end do
    allocate(tmp(i))
    tmp(:) = a(1:i)
    call move_alloc(tmp, a)
   ```
3. **I do no longer recommend this. Pointers can be confusing and create weird and hard-to-debug bugs.** But I leave it in for posterity: Create a linked list (here using a stack)

   ```
    type t_node
        integer :: value
        type(t_node), pointer :: next => NULL()
    end type t_node

    type(t_node), pointer :: list, tmp
    integer, allocatable :: a(:), i, n

    nullify(list)
    nullify(tmp)

    do
         allocate(tmp)
         tmp % value = <value>
         tmp % next => list
         list => tmp
         nullify(tmp)
         if (<finished>) exit
         n = n + 1
    end do
    allocate(a(n))
    do i = n, 1, -1
        a(i) = list % value
        tmp => list
        list => list % next
        deallocate(tmp)
    end do
   ```

Comment: And let's not forget `a=[a,i]`.

Comment: wait, what? Are you pulling my leg?

Comment: For `a` an allocated allocatable integer array, it's perhaps closest to the MATLAB of the question.  My fragment's just an array constructor with automatic reallocation on intrinsic assignment (not F90, naturally but neither is `move_alloc`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i dont know what is allocation but i will try to figure it out

Comment: If you've never used allocatable arrays before, check out this info: http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_11.html -- oh, and don't use pointers (as in my 3rd option) until you know exactly what you're doing. Pointers can be very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The way I read your question, you have a subroutine that needs to fill an array, but that array is of unknown size, and you do not want to pass in the size.  So you do NOT want this:

```
SUBROUTINE FILL( A, N )
    INTEGER N
    INTEGER A(N)
    INTEGER I
    DO I=1,N
        A(I) = I
    END DO
END SUBROUTINE FILL
```

Instead, you want to get the `SIZE` of the array:

```
SUBROUTINE FILL( A )
  INTEGER A(:)
  INTEGER I
  DO I=1,SIZE(A)
     A(I) = I
  END DO
END SUBROUTINE FILL
```

Comment: i did not understand the second code, what do you mean by getting the size of the array

Comment: In the `DO` loop, the loop ends when `I .GT. SIZE(A)`.  `SIZE` is a Fortran intrinsic function that returns the dimensions of the array.

Comment: Oh ok i got it !