# Passing an allocatable array to a subroutine gives 'signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault' error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, allocation

I have an array `sort_cent` which is a two dimensional array and unallocated initially. When I call the subroutine rbind by `call subroutine rbind(sort_cent,tmparray([arg],:))` , which modifies the array in its values and size,  signal SIGSEGV is called and the program interupts.
However, the subroutine does reaches at the end as it prints the value "End of the function" after compilation. I guess there is problem in returning the array.  Here is the code:

```
module triangulate

implicit none
contains

subroutine rbind(a,b) 
! combine matrices a and b by row
real, intent(in)  :: b(:,:)
real,intent(inout),allocatable::a(:,:)
real, allocatable :: ab(:,:)
integer              :: n1a,n1,n2,i,err


if(.not. allocated(a)) then
n2 = size(b,2)

n1a = 0
n1 = n1a + size(b,1)
allocate (ab(n1,n2))
print*,shape(ab),n1a
! if(n1a .ne. 0) then
! ! ab(:n1a,:)   = a
! ab(1:n1a,:)   = a
! ab(n1a+1:,:) = b
 
! else
 ab(n1a+1:,:) = b

 allocate(a,source=ab)

!  print*,a

 if (allocated(ab)) deallocate(ab, stat=err)
 if (err /= 0) print *, "ab: Deallocation request denied"

! endif

else

print*,"In the else part"
n2 = size(b,2)
! if (size(b,2) /= n2) stop "need size(a,2) == size(b,2)"
n1a = size(a,1)
n1 = n1a + size(b,1)
allocate (ab(n1,n2))
print*,shape(ab),n1a
! if(n1a .ne. 0) then
! ab(:n1a,:)   = a
ab(1:n1a,:)   = a
ab(n1a+1:,:) = b
 
deallocate(a)
allocate(a,source=ab)
deallocate(ab)

endif
! call MOVE_ALLOC(ab,a)

do i=1,size(a,1)
print*,a(i,:)
end do

print*,shape(a)
print*,"End of the function"

! deallocate(a)
! return
end subroutine rbind

end module
```

And the subroutine which calls the above subroutine is:

```
subroutine sortanticlockwise(triangle,c,coord,sort_cent)

real,intent(in)::coord(:,:)
integer,intent(in)::triangle(:)
real,allocatable,intent(inout)::sort_cent(:,:)
integer,intent(in)::c(:)
real,allocatable::tmparray(:,:),tmp(:,:)
integer::i,j,k,ISTAT
real::pi
real,allocatable::dist(:)
real ,allocatable::angles(:)
real::center(1,2)
integer,allocatable::arg(:)
center=reshape([1,0], shape=[1,2])
pi=4*atan(1.0)

! allocate(sort_cent(0,2), STAT = ISTAT )
! IF ( ISTAT .NE. 0 ) THEN
! WRITE( *, '( A, I10)' ) 'Buffer allocation failed: STAT=', ISTAT
! STOP
! END IF


j=0
do i=1,1
  allocate(tmparray(size(triangle(j+1:c(i)+j)),2))
  ! allocate(tmp(size(triangle(j+1:c(i)+j)),2))  !!Fixed
  ! print*,size(triangle(j+1:c(i)+j))

  tmparray=coord([triangle(j+1:c(i)+j)],:) ! * Fixed
  j=j+c(i)
  ! print*,size(tmparray)

  allocate(dist(size(tmparray,1)))
  allocate(angles(size(tmparray,1)))
  allocate(arg(size(tmparray,1)))



  dist=norm2(tmparray-spread(center(1,:),1,size(tmparray,1)),2)  ! *Correct till here


  where (tmparray(:,2) >0 ) 
  angles= acos((tmparray(:,1)-1)/dist)
  elsewhere
  angles= 2*pi- acos((tmparray(:,1)-1)/dist)
    
  end where

  ! arg=argsort(angles)
  arg=argsort(angles)  

!!!!!
open(103,file='angles1.out', status='replace', action='write')

do k=1, size(arg)
write(103,*) arg(k)
end do
close(103)


!!!!

print*,allocated(sort_cent)



 call rbind(sort_cent,tmparray([arg],:))
   print*,"Correct"



  deallocate(tmparray)
  deallocate(dist)
  deallocate(angles)
  deallocate(arg)

enddo

  
  
end subroutine sortanticlockwise
```

The output is:

```
F
         249           2           0
   1.14597142       3.33256181E-03
   1.14644611       6.66513247E-03
   1.14643490       1.33300433E-02
   1.14594853       1.66623611E-02
   1.14608729       2.33216006E-02
   1.14546788       2.66483724E-02
   1.14534485       3.32915969E-02

   .
   .
   .

   .

     1.14571607      -3.33803333E-03
         249           2
 End of the function

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f8d8ea23ad0 in ???
#1  0x7f8d8ea22c35 in ???
#2  0x7f8d8e63bcef in ???
        at ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
#3  0x7f8d8e6a09d9 in arena_for_chunk
        at ./malloc/arena.c:162
#4  0x7f8d8e6a09d9 in arena_for_chunk
        at ./malloc/arena.c:160
#5  0x7f8d8e6a09d9 in __GI___libc_free
        at ./malloc/malloc.c:3384
#6  0x55ccfb1a696c in sortanticlockwise
        at /home/abhishek/abhishektiwari/test.f90:156
#7  0x55ccfb1a49f6 in test
        at /home/abhishek/abhishektiwari/test.f90:69
#8  0x55ccfb1a6c08 in main
        at /home/abhishek/abhishektiwari/test.f90:3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Further, the above subroutine is again called by the line in main as:

```
real,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: sorted_centroid
.
.
.
.
call sortanticlockwise(trianglesinsurface,c3,coord,sorted_centroid)
```

I am using gcompiler latest version to compile the above program. The fortran version is also latest.

I tried suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384406/how-to-increase-array-size-on-the-fly-in-fortran), [this](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/read-data-and-append-it-to-array-best-practice/1915/6) and numerous others. However, I still kept gettting the error after implementing the solutions in the above websites. Can anyone help?

Comment: We need a [mre] to see where the explicit interface for `rbind` comes from in `sortanticlockwise`.

Comment: which line is line 156 in test.f90?

Comment: @albert Line 156 is the call to rbind `call rbind(sort_cent,tmparray([arg],:))` in the sortanticlockwise routine

Comment: If gcompiler is`gfortran` , then compile your code with maximum error checking.  Try the options `-g -O -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -fcheck=all`.  If the program is named `foo` after it generates the segfault, you'll have a `foo.core`.   Hand the core to gdb with `gdb ./foo foo.core`

Comment: It is really often necessary to prepare a full standalone [mcve]. That means an example that is isolated enough so that others are able to compile it and test it independently. We could then test your code but we cannot now. The link contains instructions how such an isolated example might be achieved. It often happens than one finds the reason for the problem oneself when isolating the [mcve].

Comment: @steve The core file might also be somewhere else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065912/core-dumped-but-core-file-is-not-in-the-current-directory

Comment: Sure, a core file could be placed in some other directory as a matter of sysadmin policy or a sysadmin can completely disable the generation of a core.  In that case, do `gdb ./foo` then type `run` followed by `bt` when the segfault occurs.  Of course, one might need/want to refer to the document provided with one's system.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `tmparray([arg],:)`? It seems you are using the [Vector Subscripts](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-0/vector-subscripts.html) feature, but in a weird way. Are you sure all the elements of `arg` are valid indexes of the first dimension of `tmparray`? Also, you will then be passing a non-contiguous array slice to the subroutine, which very often expose you to some strange corner cases.