# F2Py: Working with allocatable arrays in Fortran being invoked through Python

Tags: python, fortran, dynamic-data, runtime-error, f2py

Using `F2Py` to compile `Fortran` routines being suitable to be used within `Python`, the following piece of code is successfully compiled configured gfortran as the compiler while using `F2Py`, however, at the time of invoking in `Python` it raises a runtime error!
Any comments and solutions?

```
function select(x) result(y)
   implicit none
   integer,intent(in):: x(:) 
   integer:: i,j,temp(size(x))
   integer,allocatable:: y(:)
   j = 0
   do i=1,size(x)
      if (x(i)/=0) then
         j = j+1
         temp(j) = x(i)
      endif
   enddo
   allocate(y(j))
   y = temp(:j)
end function select
```

A similar StackOverflow post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264336/how-to-get-priorly-unkown-array-as-the-output-of-a-function-in-fortran).

Comment: Could you also post the python code?

Comment: The f2py list would also be a good place to ask, the responses are usually quite fast.

Comment: @VladimirF The code I used to invoke it in Python is: `import test; print test.select([0,1,2,9,5])` assuming that I compiled it already as `test.pyd`.

Comment: @bdforbes Thanks for the hint. I submitted and encouraged the list having a look on this page and giving me some solution ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article [http://www.shocksolution.com/2009/09/f2py-binding-fortran-python/](http://www.shocksolution.com/2009/09/f2py-binding-fortran-python) , especially at the example and the meaning of

```
!f2py depend(len_a) a, bar
```

However, the author does not touch of the problem of generating a an array of different size.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However the problem is we don't know how much the size of output array is!

Answer (score -2):

Your function should be declared :

```
function select(n,x) result(y)
   implicit none
   integer,intent(in) :: n
   integer,intent(in) :: x(n) 
   integer :: y(n) ! in maximizing the size of y
   ...
```

Indeed, Python is written in C and your Fortran routine must follow the rules of the Iso_C_binding. In particular, assumed shape arrays are forbidden.

In any case, I would prefer a subroutine :

```
  subroutine select(nx,y,ny,y)
     implicit none
     integer,intent(in) :: nx,x(nx)
     integer,intent(out) :: ny,y(nx)
```

ny being the size really used for y (ny <= nx)

Comment: No, `f2py` handles assumed shape arrays just right.

Comment: OK. Nice to learn. But I don't understand how it can do that in a portable manner...